# Creating file and directory with same name

Tags: linux, bash, file, directory

In Linux, why can't I create a file and a directory with same name. Seeing following error when test file exists.

```
$mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: File exists
$cd test
bash: cd: test: Not a directory
```

Comment: Because `directory` is also a type of `file` technically

Comment: There is a *file* named test.

Comment: duplicate: [Why can't I have a folder and a file with the same name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22447/44425), [Same folder and file name in same location](http://askubuntu.com/q/662911/253474)

Answer (score 22):

A directory is a special kind of a file - one that doesn't have any data of its own, but a list of other files it contains.

Like with any other file, you can't have two files with the same name in the same location, regardless of whether they are regular files, directories, symbolic links, named pipes, or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You misused the term *file*, which can actually be a directory, a socket or a pipe. The name `test` is kept in a directory entry which is linked to an *inode* corresponding to a file.

The file in the traditional meaning is called *regular file* in Unix, check `S_ISREG` macro in [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) call man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can create a file and a directory with the same name when you use different capitalization of the letters.

```
$mkdir Test ; touch test

$ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1002  0 Oct  8 10:52 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 1002 40 Oct  8 10:52 Test

$find -iname test 
./test
./Test
```

Comment: Am I the only one thinking this as irrelevant here. (Still useful info if not known already; Yet, it doesn't answer the question)